# Determine all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$ of degree at most $3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $\mathbb{F}=\{0,1,\alpha,\alpha+1\}$ be a field with operations $+$ and $\cdot$. Determine all irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}$ of degree at most $3$.

In order to find all irreducible polynomials has degree at least $3$, I think I need to make two tables, one is addition and one is multiplication
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 + & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha+1\\
 \hline
 0 & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha+1 \\
 1 & 1 & 0 & \alpha+1 & \alpha \\
 \alpha & \alpha & \alpha+1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \alpha+1 & \alpha+1 & \alpha & 1 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|cccc}
 \times & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha+1\\
 \hline
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 1 & \alpha & \alpha+1 \\
 \alpha & 0 & \alpha & 0 & \alpha \\
 \alpha+1 & 0 & \alpha+1 & \alpha & 1 \\ 
\end{array}

I am not these two tables right or not.

For irreducible polynomial at degrees $1$, I think they are $\{x,x+1,x+\alpha,x+\alpha+1\}$

---

Can someone check those tables and give me a hint to find the remaining polynomials? Thanks

Comment: The field in question is $k = \mathbb{F}_4$, the unique field of order $4$. Note that a polynomial of degree $3$ is irreducible over $k$ iff it has no roots over $k$.

Comment: According to your multiplication table, $\mathbb{F}$ is not a field since $\alpha$ does not have an inverse.  So you may want to check your table.

Comment: For the multiplication: we should have $\alpha\cdot\alpha=\alpha+1$ and this implies $\alpha\cdot(\alpha+1)=\alpha\cdot\alpha+\alpha=\alpha+1\,+\,\alpha = 1$.

Comment: @Berci why $\alpha\cdot\alpha=\alpha+1$?